# An addEventListener with keydown results in an empty string upon the first key in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a `textarea` tag that takes in values to use for something else. When I press on a key, the value of it is an empty string. However, the keys pressed after the first key show up just fine. For instance, if I type, "hello" the value would be, "ello". I want it so the value of the first key would show up.

Here's my code,

```
const editor = document.getElementById(‘editor’);
editor.addEventListener('keydown', (event => {
    let value = editor.value;
    console.log(value);
}));
```

This is my HTML for the textarea, in case if needed,

`<textarea autofocus id="editor"></textarea>`

Thanks.

Comment: The above throws errors - what is `marked` and where is it?

Comment: So, marked is a library I am using. You can remove it, I just want the value. In fact, I should have removed it, thanks for reaching out!

Comment: @icantfindmyspider try access value from `evt.target.value` instead of `editor.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all the characters as you type use the `keyup` rather than `keydown` as the event type.

```js
editor.addEventListener('keyup',function(e) {
    let value = this.value;
    let preview=document.getElementById('preview');
    console.log(value);
    preview.innerHTML=value;
});
```

```html
<textarea autofocus id="editor"></textarea>
<div id='preview'></div>
```

Comment: This is what I did, it also works 
```
editor.addEventListener('keyup', (event => {
    let key = this.value;
    let value = editor.value;
    console.log(value);
}));
```
For some reason this also works. Anyways, thanks for your input and have a nice day.